# 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, entity-framework

I wrote a rather simple code (client server based on WCF and Windows form).
i was trying to update the db so that i could test my code and i encounterd the above exception.
Any ideas how to solve it?

```
      // For testing 
      public void updateTable() 
      {
        using (var db = new overlayDBEntities())
        {
            var overlaydb = new overlayData
            {
                DeviceId = "1111",
                TimestampUTC = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9),
                OverlayData1 = "Random Text"
            };

            db.overlayData.Add(overlaydb);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            var overlaydb1 = new overlayData
            {
                DeviceId = "1111",
                TimestampUTC = new DateTime(2000, 2, 2, 10, 10, 10),
                OverlayData1 = "seconed seconed seconed "
            };

            db.overlayData.Add(overlaydb);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ec) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ec.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use ex.ToString or the debugger to get some useful information.

Comment: You need some kind of inner exception to get at the details of your problem, the exception message you are reporting just tells us that the DB failed to update, an inner exception will have probably have a SQL error message.

Comment: any idea how i do that?

Comment: i can see that it happens after exe this line

Comment: 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll'

Comment: You need to update database or insert record into db ?

Comment: Can you please share the overlayData table info? Column details of the table

Comment: The question was asked three years ago. I no longer have access to the db and I can't share it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to update Row if already Exists in database so dont use context.Add();you can use as follows.

```
    var overlaydb1 = new overlayData
    {
      DeviceId = "1111",
      TimestampUTC = new DateTime(2000, 2, 2, 10, 10, 10),
      OverlayData1 = "seconed seconed seconed "
    };

    try
    {
      db.overlayData.Attach(overlaydb1);
      db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(overlaydb1, EntityState.Modified);
      db.SaveChanges();
    }

    catch (Exception ec) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ec.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This same Error is also appear when user forget to add `Primery key` in particular table .. and then add data through application.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the type of your datetime. sqlsever has more than one datetime. if you check your inner exception, you may see the type that you are trying to put in your table and the type it actually needs. conversion cant be done automatically and you should change it in the table or convert it in your code.
it can be datetime, datetime2 (7), etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to Lan,

"The error message details all that you need to know:

Additional information: The model backing the 'AppraisalDBContext' context has changed since the database was created.Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?

It means one of your classes use in the AppraisalDBContext has changed, but the database hasn't been updated so is now out of date. You need to update this use Code First migrations."

From [The Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128167/an-exception-of-type-system-invalidoperationexception-occurred-in-entityframew)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple records of data with the same primary key overlap when `add`, causing the same error

You should review your primary key settings

Answer (score -2):

```
using Code first approach .
How to define primary key in Web API.

Eg:- Model Class
  public class Categories
    {
        [Key]
        public int cateId { get; set; }
        public string cateName { get; set; }
    }
Controller Class:-  Categories Controller
 public bool AddCate(Categories preg)
        {            
            db.Categories.Add(preg);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
Context Db Class
  public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TestingWebApi.Models.Categories> Categories { get; set; }
 Error:-"System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException",
```

Answer (score -4):

Below is the procedure to solve the System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException.
Please follow the instructions.

Happy Coding !!!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx

Best Regards,
Thet Tin Oo

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post links as answers. If the page disappears, your answer becomes useless. Use the information to build your answer and use the link as reference only. Thanks.