# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make dropdownlist for department name. I am using MVC5. I saw too much solution on stack overflow but I never found valuable solution related to MVC5.

```
Database Name : AppraisalDBContext
Table Name :  Department
Column Name : deptID (Primarykey)
              deptName (department name)
              Description
```

I am getting this error :

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in  EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The model backing the 'AppraisalDBContext' context has changed since the database was created.Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?
```

**Code:**

Controller class Name (DepartmentController.cs):

```
public ActionResult Index(string depName)
{
    var DeptLst = new List<string>();          
    var GenreQry = from d in db.Department
                   orderby d.deptName
                   select d.deptName;

    DeptLst.AddRange(GenreQry);                // Here I am confusing
    ViewBag.depName = new SelectList(DeptLst); // Here I am confusing
    var depts = from m in db.Department        // Here I am confusing
                select m;


    return View(depts);
}
```

Model class Name (Departments.cs) :

```
namespace appraisalProject.Models
{
    [Table("Department")]
    public class Departments
    {
        [Key]
        public int deptId { get; set; }
        public string deptName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Model class Name (AppraisalDBContext.cs) :

```
namespace appraisalProject.Models
{
    public class AppraisalDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Departments> Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>
    Genre: @Html.DropDownList("depts", "All")
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message details all that you need to know:

> Additional information: The model backing the 'AppraisalDBContext' context has changed since the database was created.Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?

It means one of your classes used in the `AppraisalDBContext` has changed, but the database hasn't been updated so is now out of date. You need to update this using Code First migrations.

Here is a nice [blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) walking you through the process.

Comment: Thanks lan. This link also helpfull for me : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2):

lan's answer helped me. The problem was, i had updated the model classes but the database had still the old definition. I thought the Initializer ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges<> should reset the database on new calls, thats what i read on msdn. Turns out, the initializer is not called. So i dropped the database manually with:

```
new MyDbContext().Database.Delete();
```

in the WebApiConfig's register() Methode.

After that, the initializer is called on next startup and the db schema is updated.