# how to edit in asp.net mvc 5 using view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a problem with edit and details in MVC 5 I use `ViewModel` in my application and this is my `ViewModel` code:

```
public class HeadsViewModel
{
    public int h_id { get; set; }
    public string h_no { get; set; }
    public string titles { get; set; }
    public string h_initials { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string cell { get; set; }
    public string tel_h { get; set; }
    public int title_id { get; set; }
    public string flatName { get; set; }
    public string flatNo { get; set; }
    public string strname { get; set; }
    public string strNo { get; set; }
    public string suburb { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string tel_w { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public string cell2 { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string province { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int postalcode { get; set; }
    public string zone { get; set; }
    public bool isHa { get; set; }
    public int addtype { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        var member = (from h in db.Members
                      join j in db.Contacts on h.m_id equals j.m_id
                      join x in db.Addresses1 on h.phys_addid equals x.PhysAddID
                      join f in db.Titles on h.title_id equals f.title_id
                      where h.m_id == id
                      select new
                      {
                          title_id = h.title_id,
                          memType_id=h.Memtype_Id,
                          marital_id = h.maritialid,
                          m_id = h.m_id,
                          initials = h.initial,
                          fname = h.fname,
                          lname = h.lname,
                          dob = h.dob,
                          active= h.Active,

                          religion = h.religion,
                          occupation = h.occupation,
                          company = h.company,
                          note = h.Note,

                          employed = h.employed,
                          reg = h.reg_date,
                          accnumb = h.AccNumb,

                          agegroup = h.AgeGrp,
                          email = j.Email,
                          cell = j.cell,
                          cell2 = j.cell2,
                          tel_w = j.tel_w,
                          tel_h = j.tel_h,
                          fax = j.fax,
                          flatno = x.flatNo,
                          flatname = x.flatName,
                          strname = x.strname,
                          strno = x.strNo,
                          suburb = x.Suburb,
                          city = x.City,
                          province = x.Province,
                          country = x.Country,

                          zone = x.zone,
                          postalCode = x.PostalCode,


                      }).First();

        var viewmodel = new MembersViewModel();

        viewmodel.title_id = member.title_id;
        viewmodel.maritialid = (int)member.marital_id;
        viewmodel.m_id = member.m_id;
        viewmodel.Memtype_Id = (int)member.memType_id;

        viewmodel.initial = member.initials;
        viewmodel.fname = member.fname;
        viewmodel.lname = member.lname;
        viewmodel.dob = member.dob;
        viewmodel.active = (bool)member.active;
        viewmodel.religion = member.religion;
        viewmodel.occupation = member.occupation;
        viewmodel.company = member.company;
        viewmodel.note = member.note;

        viewmodel.regdate = member.reg;
        viewmodel.accNumb = member.accnumb;

        viewmodel.agegroup = member.agegroup;
        viewmodel.email = member.email;
        viewmodel.cell = member.cell;
        viewmodel.cell2 = member.cell2;
        viewmodel.tel_h = member.tel_h;
        viewmodel.tel_w = member.tel_w;
        viewmodel.fax = member.fax;
        viewmodel.flatName = member.flatname;
        viewmodel.flatNo = member.flatno;
        viewmodel.strname = member.strname;
        viewmodel.strNo = member.strno;
        viewmodel.suburb = member.suburb;
        viewmodel.city = member.city;
        viewmodel.province = member.province;
        viewmodel.country = member.country;



        try
        {


            viewmodel.postalcode = (int)member.postalCode;
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        ViewBag.MaritialType = new SelectList(db.Maritials, "Maritialid", "MaritialType", viewmodel.maritialid);
        ViewBag.Type = new SelectList(db.MemberTypes.ToList(), "Memtype_Id", "Type", viewmodel.Memtype_Id);

        ViewBag.Titles = new SelectList(db.Titles.ToList(), "title_id", "Titles", viewmodel.title_id);

        return View(viewmodel);


    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(MembersViewModel vm)
    {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {



            var member = db.Members.Find(vm.m_id);
            var add = db.Addresses1.Find(vm.PhysAddID);
            var con = db.Contacts.Find(vm.m_id);






                member.title_id = vm.title_id;
                member.maritialid = (int)vm.maritialid;
                member.m_id = vm.m_id;
                member.Memtype_Id = (int)vm.Memtype_Id;

                member.initial = vm.initial;
                member.fname = vm.fname;
                member.lname = vm.lname;
                member.dob = vm.dob;
                member.Active = (bool)vm.active;
                member.religion = vm.religion;
                member.occupation = vm.occupation;
                member.company = vm.company;
                member.Note = vm.note;

                member.reg_date = vm.regdate;
                member.AccNumb = vm.accNumb;

                member.AgeGrp = vm.agegroup;



                con.Email = vm.email;
                con.cell = vm.cell;
                con.cell2 = vm.cell2;
                con.tel_h = vm.tel_h;
                con.tel_h = vm.tel_w;
                con.fax = vm.fax;
                add.flatName = vm.flatName;

                add.flatNo = vm.flatNo;
                add.strname = vm.strname;
                add.strNo = vm.strNo;
                add.Suburb = vm.suburb;
                add.City = vm.city;
                add.Province = vm.province;
                add.Country = vm.country;

                try
                {


                    add.PostalCode = (int)vm.postalcode;
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
                ViewBag.MaritialType = new SelectList(db.Maritials, "Maritialid", "MaritialType", vm.maritialid);
                ViewBag.Type = new SelectList(db.MemberTypes.ToList(), "Memtype_Id", "Type", vm.Memtype_Id);

                ViewBag.Titles = new SelectList(db.Titles.ToList(), "title_id", "Titles", vm.title_id);
                db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(add).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(con).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();


                return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        return View(vm);
```

}

**View:**

```
@model parishV3.Model.HeadViewModel
```

My problem is that *I want to use view model on my edit code and details code not tables.* Please can you assist me with the code.

Now Get edit Code is working , but the problem is Post edit code is not work can you please help.

Comment: After `Head head = db.Heads.Find(id);` initialize an instance of your view model and map the properties of `head` to your model and return that. Tools like [automapper](https://automapper.codeplex.com/) can help. Note also since you have a view model, it could include the property for your `SelectList`.

Comment: I can't see any data in your viewmodel. you are editing and getting detail on the basis of id. so I am afraid you need to use the tables only.

Comment: @mukund so can you assist me with the code that will getting data from 3 different tables then if that's the case

Comment: you can use linq query for getting data from 3 tables by doing join and then create object of ViewModel and set the property.

Comment: Ok I've figured out what the problem is... It seems I'm not able to get the ID for the line that needs to be updated, I know this because I used a breakpoint and it's telling me that the ID is 0. When I type the ID on the address bar it works (http://localhost:49230/Members/Edit/10). Please help me find a way to do this by clicking the 'Edit' link in my Index. @Mukund

Comment: @Mukund thank you very much its working now, the problem was id, it was not selected in the index action results.

Comment: @makund can u please assist me here, now the problem is action post  it must be the same with the one for get or ?

Comment: You can use different `viewmodel`s on each page by simply having a model converter on controller side and then push the appropriate model to the target view. This adds more ambiguities to your project. try to use 1 `viewmodel` for your purpose :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May help, try the below.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Head head)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(head).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
//Use automapper to map the objects or assign the data as below                 
    HeadViewModel headViewModel = new HeadViewModel {
    // Assign the property value from the table object 
    };
    ViewBag.title_id = new SelectList(db.Titles, "title_id", "Titles", head.title_id);
    return View(headViewModel);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Head head = db.Heads.Find(id);
    if (head == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

//Use automapper to map the objects or assign the data as below                 
HeadViewModel headViewModel = new HeadViewModel {
    // Assign the property value from the table object
    };
    return View(headViewModel);
}
```

To use three different tables you must modify your viewModel like,

```
public class HeadViewModel
{
    public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
    public Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
    public Table3 Table3 { get; set; }
}

public class Table1
{
    public int column1 { get; set; }

    public string column2 { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
    public int column1 { get; set; }

    public string column2 { get; set; }
}

public class Table3
{
    public int column1 { get; set; }

    public string column2 { get; set; }
}
```

While binding the data in the controller do as following,

```
        HeadViewModel headViewModel = new HeadViewModel
        {
            Table1 = new Table1
            {
                column1 = 0, // you data from the DB table object
                column2 = ""// you data from the DB table object
            },
            Table2 = new Table2
            {
                column1 = 0, // you data from the DB table object
                column2 = ""// you data from the DB table object
            },
            Table3 = new Table3
            {
                column1 = 0, // you data from the DB table object
                column2 = ""// you data from the DB table object
            }
        };
        return View(headViewModel);
```

**Updated**
It seems you are returning 3 view models on post method which certainly not possible whereas you must use the view model that was binded to the view.

The view model that was binded to the view 'Edit' is 'MembersViewModel' so your Post action method should look like,

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(MembersViewModel members)
{
   // From here you may want to again map the data from MembersViewModel to the table objects and do the rest of operation as you have done below
   // 1. Get the data table objects
   // 2. Assign the data from the MembersViewModel to the respective data tables which is similarly done in [HttpGet] method.
   // 3. Then save the changes as below.
        db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(add).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(con).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Updated Oct 20**
Instead of writing,

```
db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

try the below,

```
db.EntityClass.Attach(member);
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(member, EntityState.Modified);
```

here EntityClass is the class that is generated automatically for the member. And do the same for the other tables too.

Comment: @venkatesh when you want to edit in 3 different tables how do show those tables on POST ACTION CODE?

Comment: Check the modified answer and modify the model accordingly to your requirement.

Comment: Venkant can you please check my updated code on top.

Comment: @venkant "From here you may want to again map the data from MembersViewModel to the table objects and do the rest of operation as you have done below" can you please expand the your explaination   here because i cant move now.

Comment: @sibonile I have briefed the things you asked if I understood you correctly. See the updated answer.

Comment: @venkant my error "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in parishV3.dll but was not handled in user code" and Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. check my updated code

Comment: @sibonile, you should be updating your table object value by view model object value like member.title_id = vm.title_id; not as vm.title_id = member.title_id;. Assign the other table object as same. And also check your table object is not null before accessing the table object members else you will get the null exception and also do null before type casting, better you use the Convert.ToInt32() like this for type casting which will handle null values.

Comment: my problem is here now my m_id display 0 and phys_addid display null. var member = db.Members.Find(vm.m_id);
var add = db.Addresses1.Find(vm.phys_addid);
var con = db.Contacts.Find(vm.m_id);

Comment: Do you have your m_id and phys_addid as hidden fields in your view else they will show as null. Since only the input field elements value will be retained on post back.

Comment: @vekant thank you very much for your time on assisting me, that one is working but now another error on savechanges."An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code" and Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: @sibonile Your code is not yet updated with the comments I posted above as still I see the binding of table object values to viewmodel object which is incorrect which would cause the exception to occur.

Comment: " ObjectStateManager has an error. which says"parishV3.Models.ParishDBSQLEntities' does not contain a definition for 'ObjectStateManager' and no extension method 'ObjectStateManager' accepting a first argument of type 'parishV3.Models.ParishDBSQLEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @sibonile Did you include the namespace using System.Data.Objects;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i even tried this one "System.data.entity.core.objets" its not working

Comment: @vekant can you please check my last comments

Comment: can you please check my comments

Comment: Try to add the reference.

Comment: Can you please go through the SO post which defines the similar problem you have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424058/system-data-entity-infrastructure-dbupdateexception-occurred-in-entityframewor

Comment: its working now thank you very much for assiting me without you and im nothing without your assistance and your patience

Comment: @sibonile We all have skills we required anyway i'm glad to hear that I'm to help you out to achieve. If you believe it will be helpful for others then can you mark as answer. Thanks.

Comment: ok i already did that i cant even vote cause still new here i dont have reputation

Comment: @sibonile ok, no issues. Keep querying.