# An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Model compatibility cannot be checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Registration")]
    public ActionResult Registration_Get()
    {
        //Contry();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Registration")]
    public ActionResult Registration_Post()
    {
        Registration register = new Registration();
        TryUpdateModel(register);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AddStudent(register);

            return RedirectToAction("Registration");
        }

        return View(register);
    }

    public ActionResult AddStudent(Registration r)
    {
        OQContext db = new OQContext();
        db.Registrations.Add(r);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }

}
```

I want to save form data to database table but an exception occure in ***AddStudent*** action method on ***db.Registrations.Add(r);***

Comment: Handle the exception so you can identify the error.  Use a try/catch block to catch the exception and examine it, it's trying to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Debug the program and inspect the exception, inner exceptions as well as the stack trace. That should help you figure out the issue. Posting the entire exception information here will also allow **us** to help **you**.

Comment: look at above code the error is on ***db.savechanges();***. Error detail is:System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Error has been resolved, there were the problem in connection with database which i have resolved by changing ***server=.;*** to ***server=BeCool\SQLEXPRESS;*** in connectionstring

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller to

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Registration")]
public ActionResult Registration_Get()
{
    //Contry();
    return View();
} 

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Registration")]
public ActionResult Registration_Post(Registration r)
{
    //This needs to come from the view
    //Registration register = new Registration();
    //TryUpdateModel(r);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        AddStudent(r);

        return RedirectToAction("Registration");
    }

    return View(r);
}
```

You are not yet passing the model from the view

Comment: now the error is ***system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception' occurred in entityframework.dll***

Comment: Are you updating or saving the data? also make sure that your primary key is auto incremented. Show stack trace or look here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424058/system-data-entity-infrastructure-dbupdateexception-occurred-in-entityframewor

Comment: I am trying to save data @Bosco

Comment: Which line throws this error. The error says update. Did you look at the link I sent?

Answer (score -2):

Change controller methods like this :

```
   public ActionResult AddStudent()
   {
        return View();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult AddStudent(Registration r)
   {
     try
     {
      OQContext db = new OQContext();
       db.Registrations.Add(r);
       db.SaveChanges();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
     }
     return View();
   }
```

Comment: So he should swallow the error and let the user think everything is OK?

Comment: I suspect the OP wants to *solve* the error, not *ignore* it.